# Serlvet's request.getParameter and onclick use

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

When clicking an image i want to submit to servlet1 and determine which image was clicked. the asnwer should be redirected to index.jsp and be shown after "clicking status". how can i make it work on the servlet side? how can i use request.getParameter to determine which image was clicked?

index.jsp (partial)

```
<% 

String message = "NoImageWasClicked";
if (session.getAttribute("message") != null) {
    message = session.getAttribute("message");
}

%>

<form method="post" action="servlet1">
      <input id='img1' type='image' onclick='submit()'/>
      <input id='img2' type='image' onclick='submit()'/>
      <input id='img2' type='image' onclick='submit()'/>
      Clicking status: <%=message%>
</form>
```

servlet1:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");        
        request.getParameter ( ??????????? )
        ???????
        request.getSession().setAttribute("message", ????????);
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?If you are using `<input type=image>` to show buttons.Then this is not the proper way

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use any onclick handler to submit the form. That's what an input of type image does natively. Change the form method to `get` and analize the browser location bar to see which parameters are sent. Or use Firebug. Or read [the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#image-button-state-type-image) of the input tag or type image:

> The coordinate is sent to the server during form submission by sending
>   two entries for the element, derived from the name of the control but
>   with ".x" and ".y" appended to the name with the x and y components of
>   the coordinate respectively.

Comment: i updated my doc: <form method="post" action="servlet1">. i simplified this example. in the original code the servlet should do a lot of calculation regarding the clicked image and then give back an answer to be shown on the JSP file. your answer still the same for that?

Comment: Yes. I don't see what it changes. When you click on an input of type image, it submits the form with imageName.x and imageName.y as request parameters. What you're doing in the servlet doesn't change anything to that.